# Is there any way to render two Angular components in the same jasmine file?

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular-test

I would like to pretend an integration test with two angular components, in order to do that, I need render both. Can we do that? Is a good practice?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can and it will involve something like [this](https://angular.io/guide/testing-components-scenarios#component-inside-a-test-host). It can be a good idea depending what it is you're trying to do.

Try:

```
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
.....
// put this on top of the describe
@Component({
  template: `
    <component-1
      [hero]="hero" (selected)="onSelected($event)">
    </component-1>
    <component-2></component-2>
   `
})
class TestHostComponent {
  hero: Hero = {id: 42, name: 'Test Name'};
  selectedHero: Hero;
  onSelected(hero: Hero) {
    this.selectedHero = hero;
  }
}

let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestHostComponent>;
let component1: Component1;
let component2: Component2;
....
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [
    TestHostComponent,
    Component1,
    Component2,
  ]
});
....
fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestHostComponent);
testHost = fixture.componentInstance;
// get a handle on component1 and component2
component1 = fixture.debugElement.query(By.directive(Component1)).componentInstance;
component2 = fixture.debugElement.query(By.directive(Component2)).componentInstance;
```